# Is it possible to put several groovy classes in the same groovy file?

Tags: groovy

You know and I know it is possible to do in Java, provided only one is public.
But, is it possible to do so in Groovy ?
And if so under which conditions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class A{
Integer a=2
}

public class B{
Integer b=3+new CB().cb
}

private class CB{
Integer cb=2
}

assert new A().a+new B().b==7
```

Yes you can put them all in one file and just use them as you want in you main task... or what do you mean by "which conditions" ?

Comment: Suppose I use to work Java-style and I create a `main` static method in one of these classes. Will it be usable ?

Comment: Private top-level classes are prohibited since Groovy 2.0

Answer (score 9):

The differences between Java and Groovy in terms of which classes you can put in a single file are:

- `MyFile.groovy` can have multiple public classes, whereas `MyFile.java` can only have one
- `MyFile.java` must have a class `MyFile`, whereas there is no such requirement for `MyFile.groovy`